# dice question : what is best?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

got into a discussion what is best if you have :
- 5 dices
- 3 throws

You aim for getting 12345 or 23456 - doesnt matter which one of the 2 combinations.

First throw :  12356.

So we are missing a 4 to get either 12345 or 23456.

What is best for 2nd throw ?

To keep 235 - and throw 2 dices ( to get a 4 + 1 or 2 )?

Or to keep either 2356 and throw 1 dice ( to get a 4 ) ?

Remember there is 3 throws total so i assume that it might be smartest to keep the 6 and use 2 throw to throw a 4 with the same dice ? it just feels like you have more chances of getting the 4 throwing 2 dices - but ofcourse you would need to do a 41 or 46 - instead of only needing a 4 in 2 throws with 1 dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s better to keep the $1$ or $6$. If you reroll it, you just need to get it again.

Your chances of getting the straight in a single roll are $\frac16$ if you keep the $1$ or $6$ (since you need one specific number on one die) and $\frac4{36}=\frac19$ if you reroll the $1$ or $6$ (since you need one of the four ordered pairs $(1,4)$, $(6,4)$, $(4,1)$, $(4,6)$).

Since you have two rolls, if you keep the $1$ or $6$, your chances of getting the straight are $1-\left(\frac56\right)^2=\frac{11}{36}\approx31\%$ (since you get it unless you don’t roll a $4$ on either roll).

If you reroll the $1$ or $6$, with probability $\frac19$ you immediately get the straight; with probability $\frac14$ you get neither a $1$ nor a $4$ nor a $6$, and then you have another $\frac19$ chance on the second roll; with probability $\frac7{36}$ you get a $4$ but no $1$ or $6$, and then you have probability $\frac13$ to get the $1$ or $6$ on the second roll; and with probability $\frac{16}{36}=\frac49$ you get a $1$ or $6$ but no $4$, and then you have probability $\frac16$ to get the $4$ on the second roll, so in total your probability to get the straight in two rolls if you reroll the $1$ or $6$ is

$$
\frac19+\frac14\cdot\frac19+\frac7{36}\cdot\frac13+\frac49\cdot\frac16=\frac5{18}\approx28\%\;.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's evaluate the probability in each case.

I'll start with the second case, keeping $2356$ and hoping to get a $4$.

We could have $4$ on the first throw $\left(\frac16\right)$, or not $4$ on the first throw and $4$ on the second throw $\left(\frac56\times\frac16\right)$. The probability to have a $4$ with two rolls is
$$\frac16+\frac56\times\frac16=\frac{11}{36}\tag{1}$$

First case is a bit longer to evalutate. Since there are only $36$ possibilities with the roll of two dices, the best way to do this is to write all the possibilities and count the favorable outcomes. There is four events to consider.

1. Having what we need on the first roll, $4$ favorable outcomes $(1,4)$, $(4,1)$, $(4,6)$ and $(6,4)$. Probability: $\frac4{36}$.
2. Having $4$ on the first roll, but neither $1$ or $6$, $\left(\frac7{36}\right)$. Then we throw one die to get $1$ or $6$, $\left(\frac2{6}\right)$. Probability: $\frac7{36}\times\frac26=\frac{14}{216}$.
3. Having $1$ or $6$, but not $4$, $\left(\frac{16}{36}\right)$. Then we throw one die to get $4$, Probability: $\left(\frac1{6}\right)$. Probability : Probability: $\frac{16}{36}\times\frac16=\frac{16}{216}$.
4. Having neither $1$, $4$ or $6$, $\left(\frac9{36}\right)$. Then we need them both on second throw $\left(\frac4{36}\right)$. Probability: $\frac9{36}\times\frac4{36}=\frac{36}{1296}$.

Since thes events are mutually exclusive, the total probability is the sum of the four.
$$\frac4{36}+\frac{14}{216}+\frac{16}{216}+\frac{36}{1296}=\frac{10}{36}\tag2$$

We now compare $(1)$ and $(2)$, clearly
$$\frac{11}{36}>\frac{10}{36}$$
You should keep $2356$ and try to roll a $4$.

Comment: would like to have given both of you the answer thanks alot